# How do I set the compiler options?

Tags: codeblocks

I am Code::Blocks 13.2 user in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  How do I set the compiler options, such as compile under Debug or Release mode?  I don't see the options readily on the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Debug' mode and 'Release' mode are not compiler options. They are options in the
IDE for configuring the whole project (including the compiler options and
all other tool options) between debug mode and release mode.

In the tool bar beneath the top menu bar of the IDE you should see a drop-down menu
that has items **Debug** and **Release** for selecting the desired configuration.
See screenshot:-

[image]

What the various tool options will be in debug mode and release mode is up to you. The IDE has
sensible defaults. You can set them by navigating **YourProject** -> **Build options**
and selecting **Debug** or **Release** from the project tree-control of the left
before continuing. See Screenshot:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To set up the compiler go to Settings->Compiler.

To set up your projects target settings (debug, release, etc...) right click on your project and go to build options.

You may also want to take a look at the over all project settings by also right clicking on the project and going to properties.

If your just editing files on their own you have to add them to a project first (otherwise why are you using an IDE in the first place?) by going to file->new->project

Answer (score 0):

Settings ->Compiler->Global Compiler Settings->and there you can change your settings with flags or defines, and other options.